# Как закрыть доступ к голосовому каналу? Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

у меня есть код, который создает голосовой канал:

```
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if after.channel != None:
       if after.channel.id == 929392137135611984:
           category = after.channel.category
        
           channel2 = await member.guild.create_voice_channel(
               name = f'││войс { member.display_name }', 
               category = category,
           )

           role = member.guild.get_role(role_id = 929388475160096769)
           await member.add_roles(role)    

           await channel2.set_permissions(member, connect = True)
           await member.move_to(channel2)

           def check(x, y, z): return len(channel2.members) == 0
        
           await client.wait_for('voice_state_update', check = check)         
           await channel2.delete()

           await member.remove_roles(role)
```

и есть пару команд (смена имени, смена лимита, кик и блокировка канала).
как мне сделать, чтобы код заработал:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_role(929388475160096769)
async def lock(ctx):
    role = "@everyone"
    if ctx.author.voice and ctx.author.voice.channel:
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel  
        await channel.set_permissions(role, connect = False)
    else:
        await ctx.send("Вы не находитесь в голосовом канале")
        return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно передать объект роли

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_role(929388475160096769)
async def lock(ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice and ctx.author.voice.channel:
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel  
        await channel.set_permissions(discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id='айди роли'), connect = False)
    else:
        await ctx.send("Вы не находитесь в голосовом канале")
        return
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь!!!

Comment: Если это вам помогло, отметьте мой ответ как решение вашего вопроса

Comment: Я бы с радостью... Но я всего лишь день на stackoverflow... Подскажите как это сделать, с радостью отмечу!!!

Comment: А, вот, я отметил как решение или нет?